# renaming a sub-web from sbr1 to sbr33

Tags: stsadm

Should I be able to get this work with sp 2010 because I am receiving "Command line error."

```
Stsadm –o renameweb –url http://wfe2011redmond/tech/region/cProjects/sbr1/ -newname “sbr33”
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use quotes around the newname of your web.

Comment: i tried that and did not work

Comment: Try removing the trailing slash from your old subweb's url?

Comment: Yes, sir I tried that as well. we have 2 wfe. wfe1 is only used for ca and search. wfe2 is used for traffic.

Comment: Man: dont ever copy from web b/c it bring hidden characters. I re-type the whole syntax. Atleast it's accepting the syntax. Now receiving this error. "the web application at url could not be found

Comment: lol, I always paste into notepad or something to remove weird chars before I paste to a command prompt. As for the new error, does the  url work exactly as your are typing it in a web browser? No port numbers or anything needed?

Comment: i tried 80 and 8080. oh well, i used UI to change the url for the sub-web. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can rename them through the UI as well by going into the Title, Description, and Icon settings in the subsite and changing the URL.